# onmouseenter and click function doesn't works together

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, meteor, meteorite

I am using Meteorjs for my application. Here I am stucked in a problem. I have an anchor tag. I have to functions which i called on `onmouseenter` and `click` event. What i did is if user `click` on the anchor tag a bootbox prompt dialog box opened to edit the text of anchor tag. and if user 'mouseenter` on the anchor tag and stay there for 3 second then a function called which shows a bootstrap popover. My problem is if i click on the anchor tag and stay there for three the popover display and it hides the bootbox dialogbox which was opened on anchor tag click event.
My code is
Function called when mouse is entered on the element.

```
'mouseenter .edit_name': function (evt, tgt) {
    timer = setTimeout( function() {
            var id=$(evt.currentTarget).data("pk");
            $("#edit_name_"+id).popover({title:"Objective" ,content:Objective})
            $("#edit_name_"+id).popover("show")
            }, 1500);
    }
    },
```

Mouse leave function

```
'mouseleave .edit_name': function (evt, tgt) {
    $(evt.currentTarget).data("pk");
    $("#edit_name_"+id).popover("hide")
    clearTimeout(timer);
},
```

Function called on click

```
'click .edit_name': function (evt, tgt) {
    bootbox.prompt("Module Name",function(arg1,arg2){
}
},
```

But when I click on the element and stay there for 3 seconds bootbox prompt goes disappear and popover is displayed. Tell me gus how can i stop popover to be displayed if i click on the element.

EDIT:
Instead of bootbox.prompt i tried this with bootstrap.editable.js like this

```
$(".edit_name").editable({
    inputClass: 'input-large',
    url: function (params) {
        Meteor.call("renameItem", params.pk, params.value);

    }
});
```

but still the same problem. when popovers display it hides the .editable input field.

Comment: Just an aside, you are missing several ; :)

Comment: Means using semicolons It will works properly?

Comment: I said "as an aside", so it has nothing to do with your question, just about your coding style.

Comment: Okay, Thanx Morre, I will Improve it.

Answer (score 1):

Just check to see if the bootbox exists in your `setTimeout` function. If the bootbox exists, don't run the popover code.

```
"mouseenter .edit_name": function () {
  timer = setTimeout( function() {
    if ( !$(".bootbox").length ) {
      $(".edit_name").popover( { title: "Objective", content: Objective } );
      $(".edit_name").popover("show");
    }
  }, 1500);
}
```

Comment: thanx Cuberto, but i couldn't understand how to do this or how you suggested to do this?

Comment: Yes, thanx @Cuberto. It works fine . Can you please tell me how it works?

Comment: `$(".bootbox")` searches the DOM for elements with class "bootbox", which is what bootbox makes. The jQuery call returns an array, which will be empty if there are no bootbox elements. `if ( !someArray.length )` just means "if the array's length value is falsy (in this case, 0)".

Comment: yeah, understood, but it creates another problem. now it totally prevents the `popovers`. means if i don't click on the `<a>` tag and just enter mouse on it for 1500 or more seconds it doesn't show any popover.

Comment: Do you have another element with a bootbox class?

Comment: At same time i have only one. A bootbox object or a popover . In project bootbox is used at multiple places. But it displays on click and popover displays on mouseenter.

Comment: I just realized you're mixing class and ID selectors. See the updated

Comment: No no, it was not a mistake. Actually i have many object with single class and different Ids. that's why i was calling function on class name click and then performing other tasks by concatenating some keywords with the id. See the edits , Thanx

Comment: Why not just do `$( evt.currentTarget ).popover()` ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42454/discussion-between-sajid-ahmad-and-cuberto)